# Add a class to target and remove class from other elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, html, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to add a class to the target element, whilst at the same time remove a class from another element with the same class.

I have this code so far. The code works as desired, however it is saying the object is undefined and I am confused as to why that would be. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

It must be in pure vanilla javascript. thanks in advance
HTML

```
<ul class="number-container"><li class="number-item"><span class="number number-active" data-number="zero"></span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="one">1</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="two">2</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="three">3</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="four">4</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="five">5</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="six">6</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="seven">7</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="eight">8</span></li>
<li class="number-item"><span class="number" data-number="nine"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
// store elements in dom
var numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

// loop to add event listener to each button
for (var i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++) {

    // add click event listener
    numberButtons[i].addEventListener("click", changeButton);
}

    function changeButton(e) {

        // get dataset value
        var target = e.target;
        var targetDataset = e.currentTarget.dataset.number;

        for (var i = 0; i <= numberButtons.length; i++) {

            numberButtons[i].classList.remove("number-active");

            if (targetDataset === "zero") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "one") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "two") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "three") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "four") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "five") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "six") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "seven") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "eight") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            } else if (targetDataset === "nine") {
                target.classList.add("number-active");
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Your initial mistake is the line `for (var i = 0; i <= numberButtons.length; i++) {`, you need a `<`, not a `<=`.

---

What do you need the `data-number` attribute for? In `target` you already have your selected element.
Your script can be simplified:

```
var numberButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (var i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++) {
  numberButtons[i].addEventListener("click", changeButton);
}

function changeButton(e) {
  var oldActive = document.getElementsByClassName("number-active");
  // depending on your usage you could also replace oldActive by numberButtons
  for (var i = 0; i < oldActive.length; i++) {
    oldActive[i].classList.remove("number-active");
  }
  e.target.classList.add("number-active");
}
```

I uploaded a sample to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stephtr/pen/jwJKgJ).

Comment: I believe i need the data-number as when pressing on a button it will move the page to a certain position and show/hide other elements as well.

Comment: Your initial mistake is the line `for (var i = 0; i <= numberButtons.length; i++) {`, you need a `<`, not a `<=`.

Comment: Just two notes:

You don't have to call `target.classList.add("number-active");` within the for loop. `target` already contains the element clicked, so it is enough to call it once outside the for loop.

For identifying the button clicked you could modify your `addEventListener` call to include `i` (something like `changeButton.bind(null, i)` and change the `changeButton` signature to `function changeButton(selected, e)` [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/stephtr/pen/jwJKgJ) or identify the button's number (content) via `target.firstChild.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to use JavaScript to keep some previous state. One step further, the following code hide the state by using closure.

```
function selector(token) {
  var last;
  return function(element) {
    if (element !== last) {
      if (last) last.classList.remove(token);
      element.classList.add(token);
      last = element;
    }
  }
}

var select = selector('number-active');

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('number')) {
    select(target);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7qdqxzrs/

The `undefined` error comes from the condition check in `for` statement. ES6 has `for..of`, which can make things easier.

```
for (var numberButton of numberButtons) {...}
```